# SetEnv directive not working for localhost VirtualHost but works for other VirtualHost

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

### I have two virtual hosts declared: localhost and test.

Both use the `SetEnv` directive and point to the same DocumentRoot:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/mf/Sites/test"
    SetEnv FROM_ROOT 'i like tacos'             ## <- SetEnv
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost    
    DocumentRoot "/Users/mf/Sites/test"
    <Directory "/Users/mf/Sites/test">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    SetEnv FROM_VHOST 'set in localhost vhost'  ## <- SetEnv
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/mf/Sites/test"
    <Directory "/Users/mf/Sites/test">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks  
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    SetEnv FROM_VHOST 'set in test vhost'        ## <- SetEnv
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a test file **/Users/mf/Sites/test/dump.php**:

```
var_dump( $_SERVER );
```

For `http://test/` everything works as I'd expect, `$_SERVER['FROM_VHOST']` is available. dump.php outputs:

```
array (size=33)
  'UNIQUE_ID' => string 'UY7bHMCoAXIAABkbAkMAAAAC' (length=24)
  'FROM_VHOST' => string 'set in test vhost' (length=17)
  'HTTP_HOST' => string 'test' (length=4)
…
```

For `http://localhost/` things break down:

```
array (size=34)
  'UNIQUE_ID' => string 'UY7bA8CoAXIAABkZAhQAAAAA' (length=24)
  'FROM_ROOT' => string 'i like tacos' (length=5)
  'HTTP_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
…
```

### ?

1. Why does localhost not have a `FROM_VHOST` environment variable?
2. Why does only localhost see the `FROM_ROOT` environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

Few things to try:

1) This could be because you have localhost setup as a hostname which would more and likely trigger the *default*, check in /etc/hostname or optionally use a FQDN such as web.localhost

2) Another thing to try is putting *Default* at the bottom rather than top as those higher get more priority.

3) Obvious fix don't use localhost as a vhost :)

I'm not too confident with my answer but give a go (I'll revisit this when I get more time}

Comment: Re (1), `ServerName localhost:80` is set outside of any block in the httpd.conf? I agree, (3) is my preferred choice, as I'm using MAMP and it generates the httpd.conf from a template. I'm mostly asking to learn, and to help understand what's going on in case I want to take the training wheels off and fly without a GUI ;-)